# Wildcard pattern (or _ argument) with no argument

Tags: swift

I am confused as to the changeFloor(_:) arguments, in which the wildcard _ is specified and assigned to nothing. Doesn't this go against the entire purpose of the wild-card, which is to not have to re-type the parameter names? In addition, why is the wild-card variable being assigned to nothing when it should be the variable "controls" of type UISegmentedControl() being passed in in order for the action to access it.

```
@objc func changeFloor(_ controls: UISegmentedControl){
            switch controls.selectedSegmentIndex {
            case 0:
                print("hi")
            case 1:
                print("bye!")
            default:
                print("no item found!")
            }
        }

controls.addTarget(self, action: #selector(changeFloor(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a [wildcard](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html#grammar_wildcard-pattern). That's an [omitted argument label](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html).

> **Omitting Argument Labels**
>
> If you don’t want an argument label for a
>   parameter, write an underscore (_) instead of an explicit argument
>   label for that parameter.

Comment: I am still confused as to why it is left empty though. Why do they still bother to specify the parameter label when calling the method if it is meant to get rid of the parameter label.

Comment: Argument labels and parameter names are two different things.

Comment: Oh... Okay that makes a lot more sense. The argument label is defined in front of the parameter label in the function definition.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @jessy.

Also, when you `addTarget`, the control/view you assign it to is the sender. In your example, controls is assigned to the controls parameter in changeFloor.

When the value is changed, controls sends itself into the changeFloor function.

Omitting argument labels is also convenient when you want to have functions that you'd like to read easily without extra parameter labels:

```
func square(_ number: Int) -> Int {
    return number * number
}
```

Usage:

```
let squared = square(5)
print(squared) // prints 25
```

Hope this helps understand what is going on a bit better.